# White Space in UIWebView

Tags: html, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on an app in which I am using `UIWebView`. To make `UIWebView` editable, I have used an HTML file and have set its attribute `contenteditable=true`. To perform some operation, I am using JavaScript.

I have set css in HTML file. Below is the code.

```
<style>
            #test
            {
                padding-left:5px;
                padding-right:5px;
                background-color:green;
                text-align:left;
                width:100%;
                font-family: "Times New Roman";
                border-radius:5px;
            }

 </style>
```

Now, my problem is I am getting a `white margin of about 10-15px from top, bottom and left side` between `UIWebView` and HTML file loaded in `UIWebView`.
Here I am attaching screenshot for same. 
[image]

I have just started working on HTML and JavaScript(no prior knowledge) and not getting where the problem is.

Comment: padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; delete these 2

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: btw, I want padding from left & right because as user starts entering text in HTML, I want some space between text and left end. Same for right side also.

Comment: @IronManGill if I delete padding-left & padding-right, then I'll have white space from right side also.

Comment: @FahimParkar Not yet.

Comment: so white space is webview... right? I have solution for it...

Comment: Yes, webview is in white and HTML is in green. and I want to cover HTML in webview completely.

Comment: `{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}` try this..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35828/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-piyush-dubey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed use

```
{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
```

This will take HTML file to top left of webview.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all browsers add in that whitespace around the edges of the page to be backwards-compatible with like Netscape 1. In the HTML you're loading into the web view, you can use CSS to remove that:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

If you're not loading HTML into your web view, but just the direct URL for an image file, I suggest either a) wrapping that in some basic HTML (head, body, an img tag), or b) downloading the image yourself (say with NSURLConnection), and displaying it directly in a UIImageView.