# Remove white spacing in UIWebView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

In the image below you can see that there is a white space around the youtube video. It is inside of a UIWebView How do I remove this?

```
override func viewDidLoad()  {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    youtubeVideo.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lv_8StGEegc\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
  //Code I tried
  // youtubeVideo.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;
  // youtubeVideo.scrollView.bounces = false;
  // youtubeVideo.clipsToBounds = true

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the web view _itself_ is not indented?

Comment: Im not sure if it is or not. How do I check?

Comment: In any number of ways. Keep the web view empty and give it a background color. Or pause the app with the View Debugger and examine the views. Or look at your constraints and see whether you've done the right thing.

Comment: On the other hand, see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329297/white-space-in-uiwebview